Display name can contain full stops, diacritics, and underscores as well - message should mention this
Full stops and underscores should be added to the list below when editing display names.


IMO this should be dropped, as it can  also contain weird characters I don't even know how they're called. e.g. this "name" is allowed as well: ə̷͇́̍͗

diacritics. Occasionally useful, but I swear abused more often than not

Or even better, the bug is that such odd stuff is even allowed. It should be blocked as such names are noise and only distracting.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda Thank you very much.

@JourneymanGeek "more often"... huh. I'll say 99.99999% abused, there's really no legit reason to use it.

@ə̷͇́̍͗ thank Peter, he used this name yesterday as a prank. (Which is in the 0.000001% legit usage. ;))

Practically non english languages use a lot of those - and those are allowed as usernames.Sanitising those would be a lot of work, and for our non english sites, banning them would be troublesome.

@JourneymanGeek so there should be allow-list of all language sets, or even better - each non-English site will have its own allow-list.
